# What is the easiest way to print 10 characters in Python?

Tags: python, perl

In Perl it's as easy as `print "A"x10`

What about in python?

Comment: `print '10 charact'` .... ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before python3+:

```
print "A" * 10
```

In python 3+:

```
print("A"*10)
```